# jQuery TypeError - show is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button as follows:

```
<button id="onlineusers" style="display: none;">Call User</button>
```

I need to display the button based on an event as follows:

```
client.on('stream-added', function (evt) {
  alert("User is online");  
  var stream = evt.stream;
  $('#onlineusers').show();
  console.log("New stream added: " + stream.getId());
  console.log("Subscribe ", stream);
  client.subscribe(stream, function (err) {
    console.log("Subscribe stream failed", err);
  });
});
```

I am using jQuery (2.0.1) and i tried the following:

```
$('#onlineusers').show();
```

I am getting an error as:

> TypeError: $(...).show is not a function
>
> TypeError: $(...)show is not a function

I am a javascript newbie. Requesting help!!!

Comment: There is no reason to use `eq(0)` in `$('#onlineusers').eq(0)` since you are targeting the element by ID. Are you sure `$('#onlineusers').show()` don't work

Comment: `get().show()` won't work as `get()` returns an Element object, not a jQuery object. The other two lines should work though. Are you sure that `$` is a reference to jQuery and not some other library? Also, note that there should only ever be a single instance of `#onlineusers` in the DOM, so the use of `eq()` or `get()` is moot.

Comment: @Carsten Løvbo Andersen Sorry, i was using it as class previously. Sorry, Changed to update. But $('#onlineusers').show(); too is not working.

Comment: include jquery reference in your code

Comment: @Pamela then you are most likely facing the problem that RoryMcCrossan is describing. What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: are your other `jQuery` actions working ? I mean could you properly load `jQuery` to that page ?

Comment: i tried jquery('#onlineusers').show(); too..

Comment: @Pamela Please include the jQuery version in your question, and if you're getting it from a cdn, include the link

Comment: jquery version is 2.0.1

Comment: jquery is referenced in code:
<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove "style" attribute for Call User button,

```
$('#onlineusers').removeAttr('style');
```

All Code:

```
client.on('stream-added', function (evt) {
  alert("User is online");  
  var stream = evt.stream;
  $('#onlineusers').removeAttr('style');
  console.log("New stream added: " + stream.getId());
  console.log("Subscribe ", stream);
  client.subscribe(stream, function (err) {
    console.log("Subscribe stream failed", err);
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry. I did not understand. I was hiding the button by default and trying to display it based on an event ??

Comment: When the event occurs, the style attribut will be remove and your button be visible

Comment: If this worked for you but `show()` didn't then you have much bigger underlying issues.